# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE[*] SCHEMA DATABASE "; SQL statement:

Tags: sql, h2

Here the Main class :

```
public class Main {
// JDBC driver name and database URL
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.h2.Driver";
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:h2:mem:default";

//  Database credentials
static final String USER = "sa";
static final String PASS = "";



public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        // STEP 1: Register JDBC driver
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

        //STEP 2: Open a connection
        System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        //STEP 3: Execute a query
        ScriptRunner sr = new ScriptRunner(conn);
        //Creating a reader object
        Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\PROJECTS\\src\\main\\resources\\createDatabaseAndUser.sql"));
        //Running the script
        sr.runScript(reader);


        // STEP 4: Clean-up environment

        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        //Handle errors for JDBC
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Handle errors for Class.forName
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        //finally block used to close resources
        try {
            if (stmt != null) stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException se2) {
        } // nothing we can do
        try {
            if (conn != null) conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } //end finally try
    } //end try
    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}
}
```

createDatabaseAndUser.sql file which located in resourses folder :

```
CREATE SCHEMA database;
CREATE USER ADMIN PASSWORD 'abc';
```

I am trying to run my SQL script but receive and ERROR.

Here all output :

```
Connecting to database...                                                                       
CREATE SCHEMA database

Error executing: CREATE SCHEMA database.Cause: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error
 in SQL statement "CREATE[*] SCHEMA DATABASE"; SQL statement:
CREATE USER ADMIN PASSWORD 'abc'                                                                
CREATE SCHEMA database      


[42000-199]
Goodbye!
```

My SQL Dialect is H2 and I use embedded H2 database in Intelij IDEA.

I just begin learning SQL and SQL scripts, so sorry in advance if question is stupid.

Comment: @Larnu Okay, when I change dialect to Postgres and create database name; I have the same error

Comment: @Larnu Okay, It's my mistake about server.
I use H2 dialect, so how can I solve it problem?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the output from the tool that you use is garbled somehow. There is `CREATE[*] SCHEMA DATABASE` command (`[*]` is a marker from H2), but the source SQL is listed as

```sql
CREATE USER ADMIN PASSWORD 'abc'                                                                
CREATE SCHEMA database
```

and it is obliviously invalid due to missing semicolon between two commands.

Both places should be the same (with exception for `[*]` mark) and the error message should be

```
Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE USER ADMIN PASSWORD 'abc'
CREATE[*] SCHEMA DATABASE "; SQL statement:
CREATE USER ADMIN PASSWORD 'abc'
CREATE SCHEMA database [42000-199]
```

So you ether have a missing semicolon in your source file, or this tool removes it. Actually you don't need to use the third-party tool, you can execute the script directly in H2:

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
st.execute("RUNSCRIPT FROM 'C:\\PROJECTS\\src\\main\\resources\\createDatabaseAndUser.sql'");
```